# openshift oo-install:The implied host domain 'com' does not match the specified host domain of 'demo.com' for DNS

Tags: openshift-origin

all. I am trying to install openshift with one command

```
[root@demo ~]# sh <(curl -s https://install.openshift.com/)
Checking for necessary tools...
...looks good.
Downloading oo-install package...
Extracting oo-install to temporary directory...
Starting oo-install...
OpenShift Installer (Build 20140722-1618)
.....
....
....
Deploying workflow 'origin_deploy'.
The OpenShift deployment configuration has the following errors:
  * The implied host domain 'com' does not match the specified host domain of 'demo.com' for DNS
Rerun the installer to correct these errors.
```

I don't know what is the reason it keeps telling me that 'the implied host domain 'com' ...' what need to be changed?

Comment: can someone help with this? deployment manual did not mention about this, and I cannot find any clue either.

Answer (score 0):

[root@demo ~]# sh <(curl -s https://install.openshift.com/)
Checking for necessary tools...
...looks good.
Downloading oo-install package...
Extracting oo-install to temporary directory...
Starting oo-install...

### OpenShift Installer (Build 20140722-1618)

Welcome to OpenShift.

This installer will guide you through a basic system deployment, based
on one of the scenarios below.

Select from the following installation scenarios.
You can also type '?' for Help or 'q' to Quit:

1. Install OpenShift Origin
2. Add a Node to an OpenShift Origin deployment
3. Generate a Puppet Configuration File

Type a selection and press : 1

Your system deployment configuration is incomplete.
The installer will guide you through the necessary configuration
steps.

Note: ActiveMQ and MongoDB will be installed on all Broker instances.
For more flexibility, rerun the installer in advanced mode (-a).

DNS Settings

1. Installer will deploy DNS
2. Application Domain: example.com
3. Register OpenShift hosts with DNS? Yes
4. Component Domain: demo.com

Global Gear Settings
[image]

Account Settings

```
![enter image description here][2]
```

Node Districts
[image]

Role Assignments
[image]

Host Information
[image]

The configuration file does not include some of the required settings
for host instance demo.com. Please provide them here.

Hostname (the FQDN that other OpenShift hosts will use to connect to
the host that you are describing): |demo.com|

Hostname / IP address for SSH access to demo.com from the host where
you are running oo-install. You can say 'localhost' if you are running
oo-install from the system that you are describing: |demo.com| 10.1.14.145

Username for SSH access to 10.1.14.145: |root|

Validating root@10.1.14.145... looks good.

Detected multiple network interfaces for this host:
* 192.168.142.128 on interface eth2
* 10.1.14.145 on interface eth3
Do you want to use one of these as the public IP information for this
Node? (y/n/q/?) y
The following network interfaces were found on this host. Choose the
one that it uses for communication on the local subnet:
1. 192.168.142.128 on interface eth2
2. 10.1.14.145 on interface eth3
Type a selection and press : 2

Normally, the BIND DNS server that is installed on this host will be
reachable from other OpenShift components using the host's configured
IP address (10.1.14.145).

If that will work in your deployment, press  to accept the
default value. Otherwise, provide an alternate IP address that will
enable other OpenShift components to reach the BIND DNS service on
this host: |10.1.14.145|

This Node host is currently associated with the Default district. Do
you want to change this district assignment? (y/n/q) n

Do you want to modify the account info settings for the various role
services? (y/n/q/?) n

Here are the details of your current deployment.

Note: ActiveMQ and MongoDB will be installed on all Broker instances.
For more flexibility, rerun the installer in advanced mode (-a).

DNS Settings

1. Installer will deploy DNS
2. Application Domain: example.com
3. Register OpenShift hosts with DNS? Yes
4. Component Domain: demo.com

Choose from the following deployment configuration options:
1. Change the DNS configuration
2. Manage Hosts
3. Services Accounts Settings
4. Global Gear Settings
5. Node Districts
6. Display full Host details
7. Finish editing the deployment configuration
Type a selection and press : 7

Here is the subscription configuration that the installer will use for
this deployment.

[image]

Do you want to make any changes to the subscription info in the
configuration file? (y/n/q/?) n

Do you want to set any temporary subscription settings for this
installation only? (y/n/q/?) n

Preflight check: verifying system and resource availability.

Checking demo.com:
* SSH connection succeeded
* Target host is running CentOS
* Located getenforce
* SELinux is running in enforcing mode
* Located yum
* puppet RPM is installed.
* openssh-clients RPM is installed.
* bind RPM is installed.

Deploying workflow 'origin_deploy'.
The OpenShift deployment configuration has the following errors:
  * The implied host domain 'com' does not match the specified host domain of 'demo.com' for DNS
Rerun the installer to correct these errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that OpenShift requires hosts to be part of a second-level domain. `myhost.openshift.localdomain` works, while `myhost.localdomain` does not.

I entered `oshost.localdomain` as component domain (configured right after the application domain) and `0.oshost.localdomain` for the actual host and now it installs just fine.